# Why are neither functions getting called if one of them is uncommented?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have an external javascript file that has two functions and both should be called every time the page loads.
However, neither do. If I comment out the line in the js file that calls the tester() function, then runGame() is called, but if tester() is not commented, then neither run.
However, if I put the tester() function call after the runGame() call, then runGame() works, but tester() still doesn't work.

tester() doesn't even run by itself, so there's probably something I did wrong in that function. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rock_paper_scissors.js">

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <p id="game">Test</p>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Play again" onClick="tester()"></input>
</body>
```

rock_paper_scissors.js

```
var info = document.getElementById("game");

var tester = function(){
    document.getElementById('game').innerHTML = 'hello';
    //info.innerHTML("HI");
};

var compare = function(choice1, choice2){
    if(choice1 == choice2)
        document.write("The result is a tie!");
    else if(choice1 == "rock"){
        if(choice2 == "scissors")
            document.write("You win! Rock wins");
        else
            document.write("The computer wins! Paper wins");
    }
    else if(choice1 == "paper"){
        if(choice2 == "rock")
            document.write("You win! Paper wins");
        else
            document.write("The computer wins! Scissors wins");
    }
    else if(choice1 == "scissors"){
        if(choice2 == "rock")
            document.write("The computer wins! Rock wins");
        else
            document.write("You win! Scissors wins");
    }
    else
        document.write("You didn't pick a real choice");
};

var runGame = function(){

    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }


    document.write("<p>You picked " + userChoice + "</p>");
    document.write("<p>The Computer picked " + computerChoice + "</p>");
    compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
};



runGame();
tester();
```

Comment: Put the script tag after the body closing tag so that it will only load when DOM is loaded.

Comment: Check the javascript console... you can't modify the DOM before it has loaded. Move the `<script...>` tags to right before `</body>`

Comment: @zz3599 do you mean *before*? I've never heard of putting it after.

Comment: Also remove the closing `</input>`. It should be `<input type="button" value="Play again" onClick="tester()" />`

Comment: @Nile Not standard, but there's really no limit to where you can put your scripts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure element with ID "game" exists? [EDIT: Just took a better look at your code - your script is in HEAD, which means it is executing before `game` is loaded, and so it definitely does not exist.] If it doesn't, `info` is `null`, and accessing `innerHtml` of `null` will break your code. Check the JavaScript console to see the error.

You have to either move your code below the `game` element (anywhere between it and end of body will do, traditionally just before the `body` closing tag), or run your code from the body's `load` event handler, or use a library such as jQuery which provides a `ready` event.

The reason the first line (the one not using `info`) *doesn't* break your code is the fact that you are finding `game` element at the moment `tester` is run (which will be much later than the document is wholly loaded), and not when the script tag is found (which, as you notice, doesn't work).

Comment: Also thank you for that info about info. I fixed that as well.

Answer (score 0):

A good thing to always do: check the javascript console.

You can't modify the DOM before it has loaded. Move the `<script...>` tags to right before `</body>`.

Comment: Why the dv? Explain please.